# How to rebind the radcombobox?

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik-grid, telerik-combobox

i'm using two radcombobox inside a radgrid editform template

```
    <div class="art-layout-cell layout-item-1" style="width: 100%;">
    <div class="art-layout-cell layout-item-4" style="width: 30%;">
        <asp:Label ID="label_SelectCompany" AssociatedControlID="cmb_company" runat="server" Text="Company Name:" />
    </div>
    <div class="art-layout-cell layout-item-4" style="width: 60%;">
        <telerik:RadComboBox runat="server" ID="cmb_company" Height="250" AppendDataBoundItems="True" CausesValidation="False" CollapseDelay="10" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("CompanyID") %>'
            DataMember="DefaultView" AutoPostBack="true" ExpandDelay="0" ItemRequestTimeout="0" Width="80%" MarkFirstMatch="True" EmptyMessage="- Select Company -"
            DataSourceID="SqlDataSource_Company" DataTextField="CompanyName" DataValueField="ID" OnSelectedIndexChanged="cmb_company_SelectedIndexChanged" />
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="CompanyRequired" runat="server" ControlToValidate="cmb_company" ErrorMessage="*" ForeColor="Red" ValidationGroup="CompanyGroup" />
    </div>
</div> 
<div class="art-layout-cell layout-item-1" style="width: 100%;">
    <div class="art-layout-cell layout-item-4" style="width: 30%;">
        <asp:Label ID="label_CommercialActivity" AssociatedControlID="cmb_commercialActivity" runat="server" Text="Commercail Activity:" />
    </div>
    <div class="art-layout-cell layout-item-4" style="width: 60%;">
        <telerik:RadComboBox runat="server" ID="cmb_commercialActivity" AppendDataBoundItems="True" CausesValidation="False" CollapseDelay="10" DataMember="DefaultView"
            ExpandDelay="0" ItemRequestTimeout="0" Width="80%" MarkFirstMatch="True" EmptyMessage="- Select Commercial Activity -" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("EmployeeCommercialActivityID") %>'
            DataSourceID="SqlDataSource_CommercialActivity" DataTextField="CommercialActivityEnglishName" DataValueField="ID" />        
    </div>
</div>
```

and the sqldatasource is:

```
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource_CommercialActivity" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:HRSystemDataBaseConnection %>" SelectCommand="SELECT APP_CompaniesCommercialActivities.ID, APP_CommercialActivities.CommercialActivityEnglishName FROM APP_CompaniesCommercialActivities INNER JOIN APP_CommercialActivities ON APP_CompaniesCommercialActivities.CommercialActivityID = APP_CommercialActivities.ID WHERE (APP_CompaniesCommercialActivities.CompanyID = @CompanyID) ORDER BY APP_CommercialActivities.CommercialActivityEnglishName">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:SessionParameter Name="CompanyID" SessionField="CompanyID" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>

<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource_Company" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:HRSystemDataBaseConnection %>"
    SelectCommand="SELECT ID, CompanyName FROM APP_Companies ORDER BY CompanyName" />
```

and the codebehind is:

```
    protected void cmb_company_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, RadComboBoxSelectedIndexChangedEventArgs e)
{
    Session["CompanyID"] = e.Value;
    GridEditFormItem _EditForm = (GridEditFormItem)((RadComboBox)sender).NamingContainer;
    RadComboBox _CommercialActivity = (RadComboBox)_EditForm.FindControl("cmb_commercialActivity");
    _CommercialActivity.ClearSelection();
}
```

when i tried to change the company name it shows an error
"Databinding methods such as Eval(), XPath(), and Bind() can only be used in the context of a databound control."

Regards